# SQL Server 2008 R2 syntax error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Could somebody please tell me why this is causing a syntax error in SQL Server 2008 R2? It works fine in SQL Server 2014.

```
SELECT        
    CustomerId, RequestDate, 
    SUM(InitialActualCount + (KeyCardCount * x.Activity)) 
       OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId  ORDER BY RowNumber) AS TotalActualCount,
    RowNumber
FROM            
    (SELECT        
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId
                      ORDER BY CustomerID, RequestDate) AS RowNumber
     FROM            
        RequestTable) x
```

Table structure:

```
 RequestTable (CustomerId, RequestDate,  KeyCardCount, Activity, InitialActualCount)
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'order'.
>   Incorrect syntax near 'x'.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one of your issues is this line:

```
SELECT /*snip*/ sum(InitialActualCount + (KeyCardCount * x.Activity))
  OVER (partition BY CustomerId  ORDER BY RowNumber) AS TotalActualCount /*snip*/
```

The ability to add an `ORDER BY` clause in an `OVER` clause with an aggregate (`SUM` in you case) was added in SQL Server 2012.

Getting running totals was a well known problem before 2012 - see [Best approaches for running totals – updated for SQL Server 2012](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals) for an exhaustive discussion of this.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have a feeling that you're right about my issue.

Comment: Definitly your problem. But even if he was wrong, and you could use the ORDER BY in your SUM window function, I'm not sure why you'd care what the order is when you're doing a SUM, or MIN, or MAX, or COUNT.  Trying to think of where you would use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT        
   *, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId
                      ORDER BY CustomerID, RequestDate) AS RowNumber
FROM RequestTable
```

Don't you need an alias for using * ?

```
SELECT        
   a.*, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId
                      ORDER BY CustomerID, RequestDate) AS RowNumber
FROM RequestTable a
```

Comment: No, this did not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Lose the "x" as per:

```
 SELECT
  CustomerId,
  RequestDate,
  SUM(InitialActualCount + ( KeyCardCount * x.Activity )) OVER ( PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY RowNumber ) AS TotalActualCount,
  RowNumber
 FROM
  (
    SELECT
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY CustomerID, RequestDate ) AS RowNumber
    FROM
      RequestTable
  ) RequestTable ( CustomerId, RequestDate, KeyCardCount, Activity,
                   InitialActualCount )
```